# Location of the definition of open() in xv6

Tags: c, documentation, system-calls, xv6

I have an assignment that has me design my own system call. To do this, I would like to view the definition of the open system call. By this, I mean I would like to see how the actual open(const char*, const int) is defined, not sys_open (Since I know where the source code is and can read it).

In both xv6's documentation and files in xv6-public, I am unable to find any reference of the prototype of definition.
The theory of my friend and I is that it's defined in some asm file, or some .o file.
Would anyone happen to know where the actual source code is? I'd appreciate this greatly.

Tried a ctrl-f for open in the source documentation, and tried a grep over all files in xv6-public. Found nothing.

Comment: By "the actual open" do you mean the subroutine named `open` in the C runtime library, which will be a tiny wrapper around an `int` instruction to transfer control to the kernel, or do you mean the code inside the kernel that fields system-call traps and dispatches to `sys_open`?  (The latter appears to be in `trapasm.S`, `traps.c`, and `syscall.c`.  The former is not part of the xv6-public code repository; consult your instructor for where to find the C library.)

Comment: what course of OS do you take to build xv6 ?

Comment: @zwol I mean whatever is the first thing that runs when you call open() in a program. i.e: int fd = open("temp", O_RDONLY);

Comment: @alinsoar Currently taking Operating System Fundamentals at the U of Windsor. Xv6 was recently introduced into our curriculum. As for building, we simply did a github install. Our bash guy installed a make qemu command. not sure how it runs

Comment: Wonderful idea to implement xv6.  Could I find the laboratory materials posted online ?  Are you using raspberry-pi to have it run or how do you do ?

Comment: @alinsoar No raspberry-pi. I simply log in to my university's ssh, and am able to run it.

Comment: @Flacarile OK, you're talking about the `open` subroutine in the user-mode runtime library.  That code is not part of the xv6-public Git repository, nor do I see it anywhere on the PDOS or 6.828 websites.  You need to ask your instructor where to find the source code for the user-mode runtime library (often called "the C library", for historical reasons) being used for your course.  We probably can't help you any further.

Answer (score 2):

Well,

`open` is declared in [user.h](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/master/user.h).

`open` is defined in [usys.S](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/master/usys.S):

Lets see:

```
SYSCALL(open)
```

Will be transformed in

```
  .globl open; 
  open: 
    movl $SYS_ ## open, %eax; 
    int $T_SYSCALL; 
    ret
```

What happened?

When function `open` is called

- register `%eax` is set to `SYS_open` (which value is 15 (see [syscall.h](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/master/syscall.h)) and `SYS_open` is defined in [sysfile.c](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/master/sysfile.c)
- interuption `T_SYSCALL` (64 see [traps.h](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/master/traps.h))  is raised.
- after the system call returned, `open` returns too.